# my binding wont execute my fuction i tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

so im making a simple text game and when i try to attach the game() to a fuction, it doesnt execute game() and no error shows up, thanks

```
def game():
    root.counter += 1
    global cel_txt1
    global play_txt1
    if str(root.counter) == "1":
        cel_txt1 = Label(root, image=cel_bilde1)
        cel_txt1.pack()
    if str(root.counter) == "2":
        play_txt1 = Label(root, image=play_bilde1)
        play_txt1.pack()
        cel_txt1.pack_forget()
    if str(root.counter) == "3":
        cel_txt2 = Label(root, image=cel_bil2)
        cel_txt2.pack()
        play_txt1.pack_forget()

root.after(1, game)
c.bind("<Button-1>", game)
```

Comment: Your code does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to include any imports and test data needed for it to run.

Comment: what is `c`? nowhere in your example do you create something named `c`.

Comment: Read about [tkinter-events-and-bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Answer (score 0):

ive figured it out, i just wrote global cel_txt1 and is all was fixed. (btw c was a canvas i made to bind)

here is the new and improved piece of code;

```
`def game():
    root.counter += 1
    global cel_txt1
    global play_txt1
    global cel_txt2
    global cel_txt3
    if str(root.counter) == "1":
        cel_txt1 = Label(root, image=cel_bilde1)
        cel_txt1.pack()
    if str(root.counter) == "2":
        play_txt1 = Label(root, image=play_bilde1)
        play_txt1.pack()
        cel_txt1.pack_forget()
    if str(root.counter) == "3":
        cel_txt2 = Label(root, image=cel_bil2)
        cel_txt2.pack()
        play_txt1.pack_forget()
    if str(root.counter) == "4":
        cel_txt3 = Label(root, image=cel_bil3)
        cel_txt3.pack()
        cel_txt2.pack_forget()
    if str(root.counter) == "5":
        name = Label(root, image=navn)
        name.pack()
        cel_txt3.pack_forget()
        e = Entry(root)`
```